# Remote Controlled Vehicle Design

Tags: filter, bandwidth

For our term project we have to design a vehicle which has to have three functions; move forward, turn left and turn right. The vehicle will have two dc motors that will work at the same speed for forward motion and at different speeds for turning movements. And by remote controlled, I mean the controller and the vehicle will have a single wire connecting them.

The components we can use are a DC power supply, any types of resistors, capacitors, inductors, diodes, LEDs, LDRs, op-amps, transistors, push-buttons, and switches.

So we will have three buttons on the controller which will generate sinusoidal waves of 10kHz, 30kHz, and 50kHz; and three bandpass filters at the vehicle with corresponding center frequencies.

Our first problem is about the sine wave generators. We have to be able to control the speed of the forward movement and I think changing the amplitude would be the best way (with a POT for example). Our first idea was to use Wien-Bridge oscillator but honestly I couldn't figure out a way to control the amplitude. So if you happen to know any sine generator that we can control the amplitude with a single POT, it would be great.

Our first problem is about the type of the bandpass filters. We need one with a narrow bandwith and we don't want to use any inductors, but again we could not come up with a good one.

So any suggestions or ideas?

Comment: Use of sine-wave to transmit remote control commands is rare these days. Is there a reason you don't use a simple digital signal such as infra-red pulse train to encode the commands? Have you been instructed to do it this way?

Comment: Add the full set of constraints to the problem here. They are very contrived, even if you're specifically focused on audio or some other niche analogue field.

Answer (score 3):

If you control motor speed by varying the amplitude of the sine wave then your filters will have to be very sharp to reject unwanted frequencies at higher amplitudes.

Instead, I would treat each frequency as a digital (on/off) channel, and apply [PWM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pulse-width_modulation) (Pulse Width Modulation) to control the speed. If each channel is either on or off then its filter only has to be sufficiently sharp to reduce the amplitude of the other channels enough to reliably detect the difference.

If the frequencies are always sent at full amplitude then you can detect the signal with a simple comparator at the output of each filter, set to eg. 50% amplitude. *Anything* below the threshold then means that the channel is off, whereas if you used amplitude to control motor speed you wouldn't know if it was a low throttle signal or another channel 'breaking through' the filter.

The filters will slow down the receiver's response to amplitude changes and prevent short pulses from getting through. So to avoid distortion the PWM frequency should be much lower than the 'carrier' frequency. However a high PWM frequency is desired to make the motors run smoothly and efficiently.

Therefore I would use the lower 10KHz and 30KHz channels for motor selection (one channel per motor and buttons for left channel only, right channel only, and both together) and the higher 50KHz channel for PWM. A PWM frequency of 500Hz should be high enough to run the motors smoothly, yet still 100 times lower than the carrier frequency to minimize pulse width distortion.

This tone pulsing technique was used in early model radio control sets. These were commonly known as 'reed' systems because they used an electromechanical detector that looked a bit like a harmonica, with reeds energized by the audio signal and tuned to different frequencies. A screw above each reed could be adjusted to make contact with the reed when it vibrated with sufficient amplitude. Your circuit would be reproducing the functionality of this 1950's technology!

[image]

Comment: Other people also told me to use PWM but there is one thing I don't understand. As far as I understand it will work when we put it at the output of the filter; which happens to be located on the vehicle. I think controlling the velocity on the controller would make more sense, so how exactly would that work?

Comment: In my scheme the PWM is generated in the controller, with a 'throttle' potentiometer varying the on/off ratio. The PWM signal is used to pulse the tone on and off (this process is called Amplitude Modulation or On/OFF keying). At the receiving end the pulsing tone is _demodulated_ back to PWM, which is then used to control motor power.

Answer (score 0):

> ...single wire...

You might need two wires. Refer to Kirchhoff's Laws for a reason why.

> Our first idea was to use Wien-Bridge oscillator but honestly I couldn't figure out a way to control the amplitude. So if you happen to know any sine generator that we can control the amplitude with a single POT, it would be great.

If you put a potentiometer on the output of your sine generator, you can vary the amplitude easily. Wire it as a voltage divider: one side to oscillator, one side to ground, wiper is your output. You'll likely want a buffer on the output so that the output impedance of the pot doesn't affect the circuit.

> Our first problem is about the type of the bandpass filters. We need one with a narrow bandwith and we don't want to use any inductors, but again we could not come up with a good one.

Why don't you want to use inductors?

Even without inductors, a second order BPF (multiple-feedback BPF is an easy topology that only requires one op-amp, and some R&C) might suffice, and is easy to build. And you can always chain two to get fourth order.

Comment: well both the vehicle and controller will have ground connections  so I think a single wire that will transfer the sine signals will be sufficient.

And we tried to simulate a multiple-feedback BPF but its bandwith turned out to be way wider then we expected.

Comment: You can adjust the bandwidth and make it more discriminate if you wish. Higher order filters will also give you better stopband rejection. Also, do the vehicle and controller have the _same_ ground?

Comment: Yeah, they will actually be connected to the same dc supply. I mean the vehicle is actually just a breadboard with wheels, so not the prettiest thing...

Answer (score 0):

First off, you only need two signals: one to drive the right motor and one for the left. If you want straight, you just drive both motors the same. For your control, you should be aware that it is possible to find switches which have two or more circuits connected to the same button. Look up double-pole, single throw switch.

Second, you cannot count on the vehicle having a ground without a connection. Think about this - how would you make the connection? A ground connection needs a physical connection between the vehicle chassis and the controller/power supply. You need a separate wire.

Third, for the sort of frequency separations you seem to have in mind, you will need much better filters than you realize. The starting point for filters, a one-pole filter such as an RC lowpass or highpass, has a response which falls of by a factor of 10 for a frequency shift of a factor of 10. And no, that's not a factor of 10 per 10 Hz, either. A 2-pole filter will fall off by a factor of 100 per factor of 10 in frequency. So, since 10 kHz and 30 kHz are a factor of 3 apart, you won't get as much filtering between them as you think. You'll be best off making active filters, rather than trying to get inductors and capacitors. Try Googling "Sallen-Key filter".

Finally, you seem to be confused about your requirements. If all you need is left, right, and straight, you don't need to control the amplitudes of your sine waves. All you need to do is detect their presence and close a switch to the appropriate motor.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your response, we will look into the Sallen-Key filters. However three different signals are a requirement and the frequencies are determined by the instructor beforehand. Also the vehicle will already be connected to the dc supply to run the motors, so both the controller and the vehicle will be connected to the same power supply and there will be a single wire connecting them. Yeah it is not very neat but unfortunately we have to do it that way. And about the amplitude control, we need it to control the speed of the forward movement.

Comment: Oh and about the response of a filter, doesn't it depend on the quality factor? I mean I assume a BPF with a higher quality factor would fall by a larger factor with the same amount of frequency change, wouldn't it?

Comment: Yes, but high Q's are harder to achieve than low Q's

Comment: @NesliKöse - Tom is only partly right. Higher-Q filters will give sharper response, but only near the critical frequency. Good performance will require more poles, which means more stages.

Answer (score 0):

For two control parameters, and an analogue-only design, why not use amplitude to control speed, and carrier frequency to control direction? 10 kHz for straight, 8 kHz for left, 12 kHz for right. You need a DC coupled FM modulator and demodulator to recover direction, and a rectifier to recover speed. Design out the need for precision, you will struggle to achieve straight forward drive without feedback, so just trim the centre tx frequency.

For a modern design, this is a bad approach - you need really to be thinking of design cost and security which are most trivially implemented using digital designs. I can hijack your wired design using a radio transmitter, easily (however you try to defend it).